# Function If/else cannot run correctly_app android use Accelerometer

Tags: java, android

I wrote an app about `Accelerometer`. I can define to direction of movement by sensor values when you move the phone. And then i compare its value by a variable when press button.

If `Dem == 10` -> `setText("You win")` else -> `setText("Fail")` but it always show Fail.

Please help me, function If/else cannot run correctly_app android use `Accelerometer`

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener2 {


    int Dem = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(Dem ==10) textview_6.setText("You win");
                else textview_6.setText("You lost");
            }
        });

        textview_4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textview_5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textview_6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        nInitialized = false;
        nSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        nAccelerometer = nSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        nSensorManager.registerListener(this,nAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }



    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (!nInitialized){

            textview_4.setText("Are you ready");
            xChange_1 = 0;
            yChange_1 = 0;
            nInitialized = true;
        }
        else {

            xChange_1 = maxX_1 - event.values[0];
            yChange_1 = maxY_1 - event.values[1];


            if ( xChange_1 > 4 ) textview_4.setText("Moving turn right");
            if ( xChange_1 <-4 ) textview_4.setText("Moving turn left");
            if ( yChange_1 > 4 ){

                textview_4.setText("Moving turn up");
                Dem = Dem +1;
                textview_5.setText("Score"+Dem);

            }
            if (yChange_1<-4){

                textview_4.setText("Moving turn Down");
                Dem = Dem -1;
                textview_5.setText("Score"+Dem);
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your code, please.

Comment: @deHaar i add already

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Android Studio or any IDE, you can use breakpoints for debugging your app. [Breackpoint example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cqDF.png)

Just click against a line which you want to test and run the app in a debug mode (Shift+F9).

I sure that the if\else works perfectly. When the app execute line against a breackpoint - you will see what exactly amount of the Dem variable